# Custom Linq generator (AddDays) using NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, hql

I tried to include AddDays in NHibernate, like that :

```
public class ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
    {
        this.Merge(new AddDaysGenerator());
    }
}

public class AddDaysGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public AddDaysGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[]
            {
                ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<DateTimeOffset?>(d => d.Value.AddDays((double) 0))
            };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.MethodCall("AddDays", visitor.Visit(targetObject).AsExpression(), visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression());
    }
}

public class MsSql2008CustomDialect : MsSql2008Dialect  
{
    public MsSql2008CustomDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction("AddDays", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.DateTime, "dateadd(day,?2,?1)"));
    }
}
```

And my NH configuration is :

```
configuration = new Configuration();

configuration.Proxy(p => p.ProxyFactoryFactory<DefaultProxyFactoryFactory>()).DataBaseIntegration(db =>
      {
            db.ConnectionStringName = "xxyy";
            db.Dialect<MsSql2008CustomDialect>();
       })
        .AddAssembly(typeof(myClass).Assembly)
        .CurrentSessionContext<LazySessionContext>()
        .LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry>();
```

Trying to use that with predicates :

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<myClass>();
if(...)
     predicate = predicate.Or(i => i.MyDate.AddDays(date) > DateTime.Today);
```

But its not working... I always got the same error :

```
System.NotSupportedException: System.DateTime AddDays(Double)
at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your `MyClass.MyDate` is `Nullable DateTimeOffset` ?

Comment: You are right... My bad ... You can post the answer if you want... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you should check that `MyClass.MyDate` is of type `Nullable DateTimeOffset`, which is the target type for your `AddDays` declaration :

```
SupportedMethods = new[]
    {
        ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<DateTimeOffset?>
                                             (d => d.Value.AddDays((double) 0))
    };
```